# Syntactic Analysis of Spoken data,

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, minimalism

I am conducting research on spoken data, to collect the data and analyze it syntactically like to see the null constitutes etc. The question is, what could be the suitable model or framework for it

Comment: By any definition I can think of, "null constitutes" can't be seen. They can only be inferred from theoretical models or frameworks, which differ from one another. Therefore it is important to be familiar with the models and frameworks **before** conducting research. Otherwise, nothing null can be found because nulls do not exist in the data.

Comment: I have Mentioned, the framework and model would be Minimalist Program by Noam Chomsky. Suggestions are welcomed. Thank you

Comment: Good luck. You'll need it.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few options. I'd recommend either LFG or a parser for Universal Dependencies. Syntactic dependencies (and null arguments) can be directly extracted from both of them.